# "What is the best movie you saw last year" vs. "what was the best movie you saw last year"

Tags: grammar

Could you tell me which of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

> What **is** the best movie you saw last year?
>
> What **was** the best movie you saw last year?

Comment: I've made all the "movies" into "movie" as it should all be singular, but you have been inconsistent between title and body of the questiokn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct.  I would probably use "was" as it collates with "last year", but a good argument can be made for "is": The movie *is*, right now, the best movie  (that you saw last year).

Fundamentally the tense in the relative cause doesn't have to be the same as the tense in the main clause.  Tense carries meaning and so different tenses can be chosen to carry different meaning.